# how to change path extra files that get generated on publishing winform

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

I have written a WinForms code on publishing the project 2 files get generated dll and pdb file

i want only my application to be in main folder and the main folder should consist of impt file folder which should have these file

I saw some solution that go to solution explorer and then properties then publish option ..... but I cant find publish option under properties its seems like there is update due to which publish tab has been separated also in publish tab there also i cant find appropriate setting to do the task

```
is my code required ?

Please help me out 

Also I am not a expert user a coding I am just starting to learn
```

Answer (score 0):

This does need to be set in the Publish tab of the project properties, but about you not finding the Publish tab in the project properties, follow these steps:

1. Open the Visual Studio installation tool and click Modify
2. Find .NET desktop development under Work Loads to install.
3. After the installation is complete, reopen Visual Studio and you will find that there is a Publish tab in the project properties